# Regarding [biofilm] and [extra-cellular-matrix]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I have just created the [`extra-cellular-matrix`](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extra-cellular-matrix) tag, because it best describes my question. Besides, even the basal lamina alone is important enough to warrant a tag, and ECM would be the superset of that. I haven't yet checked which existing questions fit this tag, but I'm sure I will find some when I have the time to do so (and if not I can ask a few myself `=)`).

I realized that there are also some questions about biofilms. A biofilm is "kind of like an ECM for bacteria", so perhaps it could just fall under the `extra-cellular-matrix` tag. However, I'm not sure if biofilms technically count as ECM.

Does anyone have an opinion on the existing `extra-cellular-matrix` tag, the hypothetical `basal-lamina` and `biofilm` tags, and how they should relate to each other?

Answer (score 1):

ECM is different from biofilm. Biofilm is a community and a functional biological system in itself (it is not a sort of ECM for bacteria). ECM is not a functional system in itself. You can have an artificial ECM as well (as in the case of coated cell culture flasks).